# Hover div dentro de div

Tags: html, css

Eu tenho uma div que faz parte de um link que estão dentro de outra div, eu queria que se ele passasse o cursor em qualquer parte da div o houver se aplicasse tanto no texto do link quanto na div de dentro.

O hover está funcionando só que separado e não consigo de jeito nem um fazer os dois funcionar juntos.

Alguém tem uma ideia de como faço isso?

```css
.pokeBolaIn{
 background:grey; 
 color:black; 
 border-radius:100px; 
 height:20x; 
 width:20px;
 text-align: center;
 float: left;
}

.pokeBolaOut{
 position:absolute;
}

.pokeBolaOut a{
 color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pokeBolaOut a:hover{
 color: red;
}

.pokeBolaOut a .pokeBolaIn:hover{
 background:red; 
 color:white; 
}
```

```html
<div class="pokeBolaOut">
 <a href="#"><div class="pokeBolaIn">+</div>Confira nosso portifólio</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faça as seguintes correções na forma como você aplica o `:hover`. E troquei a sua `div` interna por um `span`.

```css
.pokeBolaIn {
  background: grey;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 100px;
  height: 20x;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.pokeBolaOut {
  position: absolute;
}

.pokeBolaOut a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pokeBolaOut:hover a {
  color: red;
}

.pokeBolaOut:hover .pokeBolaIn {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="pokeBolaOut">
  <a href="#"><span class="pokeBolaIn">+</span>&nbsp;Confira nosso portifólio</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado!

Comment: Na verdade foi só adicionar o css que funcionou com a div.

Comment: @JeffersonHillebrecht É apenas esquisito pra mim colocar uma `div`dentro de um `a`. E não posso te confirmar, mas me parece errado.

Comment: Estou limitado por um css feito antes, o qual se aplica aos spans e não fica o efeito que eu quero, por isso não pude usa-lo. :/

Comment: @LeonFreire é esquisito, mas a partir do HTML 5 começou a ser permitido elementos *block* dentro de um elemento `a` se o elemento pai deste permite elementos *block*. Antes do HTML 5 seria errado, sim, utilizar uma `div` dentro de um `a`. Vide [recomendação W3C](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/a.html#a-changes).

Answer (score 1):

Estava respondendo, mas já foi explicado pelo Leon na [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/216620/4808) dele, basta definir para regra de `:hover` ser aplicada quando acontecer no elemento `.pokeBolaOut`.

Mas não é necessário o uso de tantos elementos para esse efeito. Como o `( + )` é só um componente visual e não agrega valor para a página, pode ser um elemento criado com o [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) do `<a>`.

```css
a::before {
  align-items: center;
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '+';
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 20px;
  justify-content: center; 
  margin-right: .5%;
  width: 20px
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none
}

a:hover {
  color: red
}

a:hover::before {
  background: red;
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<a href='#'>Confira nosso portfólio</a>
```

Comment: Gostei da sua resposta, está bem explicada, obrigado!